# Why im getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have this Scroll event of a trackBar:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                trackbarCounter++;
                if (manualDone == true)
                {
                    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = _fi.Length - 1;                    setpicture(myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value);
                    this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
                }
                if (automaticDone == true)
                {
                    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = fiAutomatic.Length - 1;
                    long[] tt = list_of_histograms[myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value];
                    long res = GetTopLumAmount(tt, 1000);
                    long max = GetHistogramMaximum(tt);
                    GetHistogramAverage(tt);
                    setpicture(myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value);
                    this.pictureBox1.Refresh();

                                    }

        }
```

The exception is on this line:

```
long[] tt = list_of_histograms[myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value];
```

After im clicking on the trackBar and move it to the right in this case this time it went as far as to the frame/track 40 then throw the exception there.

The exception:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Now fiAutomatic variable contain 2225 indexs for example in index [0] i see: {000001.bmp}
In index [1] i see: {000002.bmp}
And so on.

list_of_histograms is a contain now 40 indexs in each index i have a 256 indexs inside for example in index[0]  i see: {[long256]} and i see in index[0] 256 numbers. 
Then in index[1] again {[long256]} and another 256 numbers and so on.

And the trackBar value is 40.

But why when im moving the trackBar to the right after 40 frames/images its throwing this exception ?

This is the full exception message:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at Extracting_Frames.Form1.trackBar1_Scroll(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\C-Sharp\Extracting_Frames\Extracting_Frames\Extracting_Frames\Form1.cs:line 1793
       at System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.OnScroll(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WmHScroll(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Extracting_Frames.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\Extracting_Frames\Extracting_Frames\Extracting_Frames\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Because indexes in an array of 40 elements are 0 to 39. 40 does not exist. You already mention that you have looked into index 0, so *you must already know this*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_of_histograms is a contain now 40 indexs in each index`

This would be your problem.  Remember that when you declare something, it indexes it from 0.  So 40 indexes would mean it maxes out at 39.  Doing `list_of_histograms[40]` is going to cause an error.

EDIT: And NOW I notice the comment on your question when I go to retag it...

Comment: @Default The comment by Jon on the question itself.